# How can I tell if a teleporter exit was picked up when I'm at the entrance?

Tags: team-fortress-2

When the other end of an active teleporter is destroyed or picked up by its builder, the end I'm facing will stop glowing and spinning.

- If the teleporter is destroyed, it will show up in the kill feed. However, that's fairly easy to miss, more so when my base is being destroyed by a rush (and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-number-of-items-displayed-in-the-kill-feed) doesn't help as much as I had hoped). The end I'm facing will also reset to level 1 if it's upgraded, but if it was level 1 to begin with then that's not going to help much.
- If an active teleporter is sapped, sappers will be planted on both ends, so that makes it pretty obvious. However, either end may still be destroyed prematurely leaving the other one intact and sapped.
- If the teleporter is picked up, the end I'm facing will *not* reset to level 1 if it's upgraded. Again, if it's level 1, it's not a very helpful indicator. Note also that buildings cannot be picked up when sapped.

Are there any visual effects or sounds I can pay attention to, in order to tell quickly whether that other end was destroyed or picked up regardless of what level it is?

Comment: I have to say your question confuses me. As you say - "When the other end of an active teleporter is destroyed or picked up by its builder, the end I'm facing will stop glowing and spinning". That seems like a pretty good indicator to me. Maybe you should explain why that is insufficient?

Comment: @Aubergine: It doesn't help me distinguish between being destroyed and being picked up.

Comment: As I said, your question confused me. I went ahead and edited the title.

Comment: Have you ever just tried text/voice chatting the Engineer and asking them if they're moving it? I know that's not exactly the most ideal situation especially in the heat of battle, but I don't see any other way you could get a confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot tell when the other end of a teleporter has been destroyed or picked up by sound alone. The only thing you can do (besides the kill feed) is to look at one end of the teleporter and see what level it is.

If it was picked up it should stay whatever level it was when picked up (level 3, level 2 with 150/200, etc). If the teleporter was destroyed at the other end it will drop to level 1.

There is a small drawback to this: the teleporter could be picked up at level 1 and is currently being moved but you may think it was destroyed.

Comment: I guess there's no reliable way to tell besides looking at the teleporter itself. The MvM update has made it even harder to tell if it's an exit or entrance because both have arrows pointing at each other (which incidentally makes it easier to troll/grief teammates).